# Videoview measure to fit a layout with exactly ratio

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I use **Mediaplayer** in android to play video online and display this on a **videoview**. The videoview is put in a **RelativeLayout** with a fixed size.

The problem is the size (width and height of video) is not fit the relativelayout, so I need to resize video to fit inside relativelayout with exactly ratio of video, but it's seem like doesn't work, my code here:

***Code to create a videoview:

```
    ...
        MyVideoView mVideoView = new MyVideoView(mContext);
                mVideoView.requestFocus();

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                mVideoView.setLayoutParams(p);

                return mVideoView;
}
```

*** Code to get ratio when video is started playing

```
    @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            mWebview.removeView(mProgressWheel);
            mediaPlayer.start();

    //        int w = mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
    //        int h = mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
            int w = mVideoView.getWidth();
            int h = mVideoView.getHeight();

            ((MyVideoView) mVideoView).setDimention(w, h);

        }
```

*** A short of My custom video view class:

```
public class MyVideoView extends VideoView{
    ...
 private ElementObject elm;
private int aW;
        private int aH;
        int additional = 0;
        float ratio = 1f;
private void caculateRatio(int w, int h){

            if(w > h) ratio = (float)w/h;
            else if(h > w) ratio = (float)h/w;
        }

    public void setDimention(int w, int h){
                this.aW = w;
                this.aH = h;
                setIsPlaying(true);

                caculateRatio(w, h);
                calculateAdditional(w, h);
            }
     public void calculateAdditional(int w, int h){
                if(w >= elm.frame.getW() && h < elm.frame.getH()) {
                    additional = elm.frame.getH() - h;
                    measure(w + (int) (additional * ratio), elm.frame.getH());
                }else if(w < elm.frame.getW() && h >= elm.frame.getH()) {
                    additional = elm.frame.getW() - w;
                    measure(elm.frame.getW(), h + (int) (additional * ratio));
                }else if(w < elm.frame.getW() && h < elm.frame.getH()){

                    int wR = elm.frame.getW() - w;
                    int hR = elm.frame.getH() - h;

                    if(wR > hR){
                        additional = wR;
                        measure(elm.frame.getW(), h + (int) (additional * ratio));
                    }else {
                        additional = hR;
                        measure(w + (int) (additional * ratio), elm.frame.getH());
                    }
                }
                else
                    measure(w, h);


            }

@Override
        public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            //super.setMeasuredDimension(1000,1000);
            setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }

}
```

I found that the override function `onMeasure(int, int)` is called multiple time before the video started playing, so that I removed `onMeasure(int, int)` function and call: `setMeasuredDimension(int, int)` in side function: `public void calculateAdditional(int w, int h){...}` instead of using `measure(int, int)`, but it also not affect anything.
What can I do to resize the video to fit exactly relativelayout with exact ratio.

Also try to change layoutparams whey creating videoview to **FILL_PARENT** or **MATCH_PARENT**, but keep wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FILL_PARENT` instead:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```